# Ordering collectionGroup by serverTimestamp

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a database using `Firestore`.

The data base is as follows:

There is a main collection called `NBDB`, inside there are documents with `uid` for each user (for example `OJQRFOyYd....`). Inside each document there is another collection called `MyBooks` and inside this collection there are documents with uid that contain the `BookID`, `DateCreated` and `Popularity`.

[image]

By using the following code I have managed to obtain all of the `BookID`s thank to collectionGroup query:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collectionGroup( "MyBooks" ).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Log.d(TAG,document.getId() + " => " + document.getData().get( "BookID"));
            }
        }
    });
```

However, I had like the data to be ordered by the DateCreated field. 
I thought first to order the database and then to use the function above, something like:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collectionGroup( "MyBooks" ).orderBy("DateCreated").get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Log.d(TAG,document.getId() + " => " + document.getData().get( "BookID"));
            }
        }
    });
```

However it is not working since my search is not inside the document of each book.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: `MyBook` or `MyBooks`? Your code doesn't match your db.

Comment: @AjahnCharles Nice catch

Comment: sorry it was MyBooks, I edited

Comment: It's a classic bug! I usually make a data class matching my Firestore structure, and inside it I make a companion object with constants for all the field names & the path, so for me it would be `db.collectionGroup(Book.PATH).orderBy(Book.DATE_CREATED)` - helps to minimise typos.

Comment: Check logcat to see if you have a warning about needing an index.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean with make a data class matching your Firestore structure?

Comment: The class would be like this: `data class Book(var BookID: String = "", ...) { companion object { const val PATH = "MyBooks"... } }`. It works well with `docSnapshot.toObject(Book::class.java)`, `colSnapshot.toObjects(Book::class.java)`, and with Firebase UI.